# Order of Python Procedures (when to put the variable in parenthesis vs. putting it before periods)

Tags: python

I'm currently teaching myself how to code and I have a very broad question about Python (and every other language). How do you know when to put a variable before a period or within the parenthesis of the function?

For example - This expression will retrieve the correlation for the dataset.

```
df.corr()
```

However, why is the parenthesis left closed without any information inside of it? Why can't you put the variable within the expression like this -

```
corr(df)
```

I understand that the first expression is correct, I'd just like to at a high-level know why. Does anyone have any videos or tools that can explain this fundamental principle of coding?

I've historically used excel a lot in my past positions, which is probably why I instinctively to put everything within parenthesis.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: See also [What's the difference between a method and a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

Comment: ALL functions must have the parenthesis. `df.corr()` Means that the Object `df` has a member function (methods) called `corr()` It **may** or not have input parameters.  `corr(df)` would be a function (not object memeber=> not a method ) that receives `df` as input parameter

Comment: May I kindly suggest you do [the full official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) ? Also if you don't have any basic CS knowledge, [this excellent (and free) book](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/)

Comment: NB: I reopened the question since I really don't think the dup suggested by kaya3 was a good match.

Comment: @Derek24, ...How did you know that `corr` existed at all? Whatever documentation told you it existed should also tell you if it's a method ("member function"), or a standalone function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, why is the parenthesis left closed without any information inside of it?

```
df.corr()
```

Because there's nothing more to pass to the function. Or, more exactly (and assuming `df` is something like a panda dataframe instance or other similar object), because the only required argument (`df`) is, in this case, automagically passed to the function.

> Why can't you put the variable within the expression like this -

```
corr(df)
```

You could do something like `type(df).corr(df)` if you really want, but that's a bit useless.

Ok, let's go a bit deeper: Python is an [object oriented language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). In OO, objects have "methods" - functions that act on the object on which they are called. In most OOPLs, the syntax for method calls is `obj.method()` instead of `method(obj)`. Behind the scene, your language's compiler or interpreter (or whatever other mechanism) actually make `obj` available to the method, so there's no need to pass it explicitely.

The point of having things this way - instead of having a standard function - is that different objects can define the same method each in it's own way, so as a "client" of those objects, you don't have to check the exact type and call the object-specific version yourself, ie:

without objects:

```
def draw_rect(rect):
    # code to draw a rect here

def draw_line(line):
    # code to draw a line here

def draw_circle(circle):
    # code to draw a circle here


def draw_all(drawables):    
    for obj in drawables:
        if isinstance(obj, Rect):
            draw_rect(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, Line):
            draw_line(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, Circle):
            draw_circle(obj)

def main():
    # a list of various "drawable" objects
    objects = [Rect(), Line(), Cicle()]
    draw_all(objects)
```

with objects:

```
class Rect():
    def draw(self):
        # code to draw a rect here

class Line():
    def draw(self):
        # code to draw a line here

class Circle():    
    def draw(self):
        # code to draw a circle here


def draw_all(drawables):
    for obj in drawables:
        obj.draw() 


def main():
    # a list of various "drawable" objects
    objects = [Rect(), Line(), Cicle()]
    draw_all(objects)
```

and behind the scene, Python will turn `obj.draw()` into `type(obj).draw(obj)`. This is called "type-based polymorphic dispatch" and is really the most essential concept in OOP.

Now Python is not a "pure" OOPL, in that in doesn't force you into using only objects and methods - you can also write and use plain functions too (our `draw_all` and `main` functions above for example), which, of course, will work as you expect.